# Trying to use Virtual Scroller in Vue 3 But the items are buffering

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, virtualscroll

I need to display a large number of data but I can't make the virtual scroller work

```
  <RecycleScroller
class="scroller"
    page-mode
    :items="store.clinicData.value[store.activeTabKey.value]"
    v-slot="{ item }"
    item-height="42"
    :key-field="'hsId'"
    :item-size="25"

>
    <div class="user">
        <p>{{ item.name }}</p>
        <p>{{ item.hsId }}</p>
    </div>
</RecycleScroller>


<script>
import { RecycleScroller } from "vue-virtual-scroller";
</script>


    <style>
.scroller {
  height: 100%;
}

.user {
  height: 32%;
  padding: 0 12px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
</style>
```

The problem is that the items are buffering and hitting into each other,how can i fix this?
And I get these errors:
1.Uncaught Error: Rendered items limit reached
2.It seems the scroller element isn't scrolling, so it tries to render all the items at once. Scroller: <div data-v-b4e148ca class=​"vue-recycle-scroller ready direction-vertical scroller">​…​​
3.Make sure the scroller has a fixed height (or width) and 'overflow-y' (or 'overflow-x') set to 'auto' so it can scroll correctly and only render the items visible in the scroll viewport.

Answer (score 1):

Add `import 'vue-virtual-scroller/dist/vue-virtual-scroller.css'` to fixed it.

Comment: You should wrap code blocks in 3 backticks (`)